# Excel display issue - ##

Tags: microsoft-excel, display

I am trying to re-format an existing excel document but some of the cells are displaying the text as ###.
Please can anyone tell me why it is happening in some and not others when the formatting appears to be the same?

**Edit**

Sorry, I should have said its not the column width - the cells are a row of merged columns and I did try making them very wide just to check. I also should have mentioned that there are 256 characters which I know causes this issue but I can't remember how to cure it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said its not the column width - the cells are a row of merged columns and I did try making them very wide just to check. I also should have mentioned that there are 256 characters which I know causes this issue but I can't remember how to cure it.

Comment: If you insert a single quote (`'`) at the beginning of the text, does it solve it?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but in this instance it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the formatting. Right click the cell and change the type from Text to General.

This is because the format you've had has a limited amount of characters and your content is more than it can handle. Changing it to general allows more characters (1024 characters). If you have more than this then that is still a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I hit format cells and changed it from 'text' to 'general' and there it was! Its only easy when you know how.......

Answer (score 0):

Normally this happens when the content cannot be fully displayed within the available column width. Try making the column wider.